# Populate Map<String,String> with entire .property file from Environment Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-properties, spring-environment, spring-framework-beans

I have this myProperties.properties files with the following content:

```
enum1 = a
enum2 = b
enum3 = c
enum4 = d
and so on...
```

My problem is how can I populate or inject all property values in a `Map<String,String>` - enum1..4 as the key and 1..d as the value from Environment variable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about `java.util.Properties` than there is no any problem in converting it to `Map` because it extends from `Hashtable` this means that you can simply convert it to `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> result = (Map)properties;
```

Comment: I am using the @ResourceProperty to read .property files.
and then I access the property file via env.getProperty("key").
Is there a way to read the entire property file from the environment and inject it to a map?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest you in this case is to load properties manually, something like that: `prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myproperties.properties"))`